# Codename One Strange Screen behaviour

Tags: screen, codenameone, custom-component

When I run the device on the simulator of CN1 I see different and strange results. Not refereed to the screen size, refereed to the components position, the button for the side bar aper on the middle of the screen.

Where I fix this behaviour?

[image]

The layout tree

[image]

Comment: I think it will depend on what layout hierarchy you have used in designer and how you have positioned them. It will be a bit difficult for anyone to answer without knowing component hierarchy. some screen shot of component list will be helpful..

Comment: I added the layout tree

Comment: What matters is how you styled the title/title area and form. Make the form non-scrollable explicitly as you used table layout which should improve the behavior see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html#table-layout-section

Comment: Thanks  Shai, to be non scrollable a form I need to do it from the the CN1Designer or in the java code?

Comment: Is the sideMenuImage the problem

Comment: I change the style on the TitleArea and is done. My problem was because I used an image as Background.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you do like this way then it should work

`Main Form -> Layout=BorderLayout
Container1 -> LayoutConstraint=North (set Layout as per your requirement)
    add those fields (containers/components) that you want as a header
Container2 -> LayoutConstraint=Center, Layout=BoxLayoutY
    Container1TableLayout -> Layout=TableLayout`

Make this Container1TableLayout as you have done in yours and add your components/buttons.

Hopefully it may work..

Comment: hope you have clear concept of Layout vs LayoutConstraint :)

Comment: I will try, but this icon, the sideMenuImage not belong to the Form I think, belong to the TittleArea

Comment: if you want to remove it then you can do like...

You can also set it by setting the commandBehavior theme constant in the Codename One designer to "Side".


Ref: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/hamburger-sidemenu.html

Comment: also make sure you are setting those images as button's icon and not as the background.